# Team Foundation Server Branching backwards

Tags: tfs

I have a project in TFS on  Microsoft's visual studio online. There is a base / trunk that, for the purposes of this question I will call "Branch 0". This is meant to have all the base features of the project. From here, we created a second branch, "Branch 1" which has client specific implementations for our first client.  The original concept is that, as we make improvements, modifications, and add new features to Branch 0, they can be merged up to Branch 1, and any other successive branches we setup for new clients.

Best laid plans though... A lot of base features were implemented in Branch 1 and not Branch 0 due to timelines and my failing at times to properly manage the development process. I would like to, ideally, merge Branch 1 back down to Branch 0, then strip out anything specific to Client 1. My concern though is, in doing so, will I create a situation where I can no longer safely branch changes from Branch 0 back up to Branch 1, or will TFS see that I deleted a file in Branch 0 and in turn delete it from Branch 1 the next time I merge 0 up to 1? That would of course defeat the whole purpose.

Comment: If you are going to down vote my question, an explanation as to why it is unworthy of being asked would be simple courtesy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always going to have this issue as long as you have customer specific code branched at all. I would work to separate those two things. You have s base application that can be customised for each customer. That is one thing, distinct, that can be versioned.

Separately you should have your customer specific customizations that do not get branched with everything else.

Think SharePoint, WordPress, DotnetNuke, or Dymanics.... Keep your implementation and development separate.

If you have to code to create customizations then use a plugin model and version your plugins...

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to merge everything back down to branch0, you can pick specific changesets. 
Failing that, you can merge down the lot and then choose what not to commit back into branch0.

Comment: A pick-n-mix branching model will reduce quality and introduce unexpected results: http://nakedalm.com/avoid-pick-n-mix-branching-anti-pattern/

Comment: I've never come across the "pick-n-mix antipattern" before.

Comment: You just described it s your answer 

Comment: If it's you that's decided it's an antipattern then you ought to add a disclaimer stating that.

Comment: Picking and choosing changesets for merging is considered, by the entire ALM community, to be a bad practice that leads to lower code quality and errors in what is shipped.